# Output individual data from structure based on timer

Tags: c#, data-structures, timer

I'am creating a "man-in-middle" style application that applies a network latency to the transmissions, not for malicious use I should declare.

However I'm having difficulty with the correct output mechanisms on the data structure (`LinkedList<string> buffer = new LinkedList<string>();`).

What should happen:

- Read data into structure from clientA.

  `if (buffer.First != null && buffer.Last != null)
  {
  buffer.AddAfter(buffer.Last, ServerRead.ReadLine().ToString());

  }
  else
  buffer.AddFirst(ServerRead.ReadLine().ToString());`
- Using an individual or overall timer to track when to release the data to ClientB. (adjustable timer to adjust latency)
- Timer on item in structure triggers, thus releasing the packet to clientB.
- Clean up free data structure node

  `if (buffer.First != null)
  {

  clientWrite.WriteLine(buffer.First.Value.ToString());

  clientWrite.Flush();

  buffer.RemoveFirst();
  }`

However I have been trying to use the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to create a global timer that triggers a thread which handles the data output to clientB. However I'am finding this technique to be too slow, even when setting the `myTimer.Interval = 1;` This creates a concurrency problem with when clearing up the list and adding to it, the temporary solution is by locking the resource but I feel this is adding to the slow performance of data output.

**Question:**
I need some ideas on a solution that can store data into a data structure and apply a timer (like an egg timer effect) on the data stored and when that timer runs out it will be sent on its way to the other clients.

Regards, House.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linked list will work, and it's unlikely that locking it (if done properly) will cause poor performance.  You'd probably be much better off using [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx).  It's thread-safe, so you don't have to do any explicit blocking.

I would suggest using `System.Threading.Timer` rather than the Windows Forms timer.  Note, though, that you're still going to be limited to about 15 ms resolution.  That is, even with a timer interval of 1, your effective delay times will be in the range of 15 to 25 ms rather than 1 ms.  It's just the way the timers are implemented.

Also, since you want to delay each item for a specified period of time (which I assume is constant), you need some notion of "current time."  I don't recommend using `DateTime.Now` or any of its variants, because the time can change.  Rather, I use `Stopwatch` to get an application-specific time.

Also, you'll need some way to keep track of release times for the items.  A class to hold the item, and the time it will be sent.  Something like:

```
class BufferItem
{
    public string Data { get; private set; }
    public TimeSpan ReleaseTime { get; private set; }
    public BufferItem(string d, TimeSpan ts)
    {
        data = d;
        ReleaseTime = ts;
    }
}
```

Okay.  Let's put it all together.

```
// the application clock
Stopwatch AppTime = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// Amount of time to delay an item
TimeSpan DelayTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0);
ConcurrentQueue<BufferItem> ItemQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<BufferItem>();
// Timer will check items for release every 15 ms.
System.ThreadingTimer ReleaseTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(CheckRelease, null, 15, 15);
```

Receiving an item:

```
// When an item is received:
// Compute release time and add item to buffer.
var item = new BufferItem(data, AppTime.Elapsed + DelayTime);
ItemQueue.Add(item);
```

The timer proc.

```
void CheckRelease(object state)
{
    BufferItem item;
    while (ItemQueue.TryPeek(out item) && item.ReleaseTime >= AppTime)
    {
        if (ItemQueue.TryDequeue(out item))
        {
            // send the item
        }
    }
}
```

That should perform well and you shouldn't have any concurrency issues.

If you don't like that 15 ms timer ticking all the time even when there aren't any items, you could make the timer a one-shot and have the `CheckRelease` method re-initialize it with the next release time after dequeing items.  Of course, you'll also have to make the receive code initialize it the first time, or when there aren't any items in the queue.  You'll need a lock to synchronize access to updating the timer.

Comment: thats an interesting point about the limit on the accuracy of timers, but it makes sense with the overhead on creating timers. Your answer makes alot of sense. Will see how it performs. Thanks.

Comment: the `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0);` if this variable were to be dynamic, I would need to re-initialize it with the new value after dequeuing items etc. (like you said in the paragraph above). Thanks.